# Internet Message Format actual version

Tags: rfc

I'm started to read [RFC2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) which reffered to very old [RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt). So what is actual RFC version of Internet Message Format and `MIME`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) obsoleted [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), which already obsoleted [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822). RFC822 is too old and only kept to find the exact information when referred to elsewhere. You can find the same information, more up to date, in RFC5322.

When some text refers to obsoleted RFCs, you can find the same information in the newer one that obsoletes the older one. The only obstacle there is that you will have to do additional text-search, because the text-structure is not kept between RFCs. Only if you can't find the information you are looking for in the newer RFC, then you should look into the older, obsoleted one.